Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.0
enter image description hereFAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.0.
Required by:
project :app
> Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.0.
flutter , dart , build gradle issue

android {
   ...
   signingConfigs {
      config {
          ...
          enableV3Signing = true
          enableV4Signing = true
      }
   }
}


Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre] of your build files so we can reproduce the issue ourselves.

Hi @tyg try to achieve the v3 and v4 signing scheme release build apk, details are updated in app/build.gradle like
signingConfigs {
config {
enableV3Signing = true
enableV4Signing = true
}
}
after updated this changes in the gradle this has been occur.

can you please  share which version of firebase_core

the above issue has been fixed by me below code has not placed in the correct place in the Gradle and also network issue Gradle not sync correctly
'signingConfigs {
config {
...
enableV3Signing = true
enableV4Signing = true
}
}'
